# android getItemViewType on onItemClick

Tags: android

I want to use getItemViewType in onItemClick event to determine current item type (1 or 2 in my case). I override `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount`:

```
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //not last item 
        if (position != getCount() - 1)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;   

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
```

For `onItemClick` :

```
                @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Integer curItemType = arg0.getAdapter().getItemViewType(arg2);
                Log.i("curItemType",Integer.toString(curItemType));

            }
```

For curItemType in `onItemClick` I get values 2 and 3 (not my 0 or 1 ) can some explain my why? 
In `getView` method `curItemType` is correct (0 or 1)

Thanks

Comment: Note that getItemViewType should return values between 0 and getViewTypeCount()-1. In your case, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you have actually set your arg0 adapter (the parent) to be the adapter that you've created (lets call it `MyAdapter` in this case).

You should actually cast your `getAdapter()` result so that the class you've written as your adapter will be used when calling `getItemViewType`, just to stay on the safe side.

Like so:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) arg0.getAdapter();
            Integer curItemType = adapter.getItemViewType(arg2);
            Log.i("curItemType",Integer.toString(curItemType));
```

Your `MyAdapter` class should contain your `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` methods

Comment: The cast to MyAdapter is not necessary.

Comment: @Hakan Ozbay, thanks for answer but I receive this error `The method getAdapter() is undefined for the type View` , why?

Comment: @Jovan, Have you set the adapter of that View to be the adapter class you have made?

Comment: @Hakan Ozbay,Yes in my case MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter

Comment: @Jovan, please see my edited answer. Have you set the parent's adapter to be MyAdapter? that way when you get the parent's adapter, you can use MyAdapter